# Запушить изменения всех веток

Tags: git, git-flow

подскажите начал использовать `git flow` в своем проекте, с открытием - закрытием фитчей, релизов проблем нет

У меня есть в удаленном репозитории ветка `master`, `develop` , как после завершения релиза запушить все в удаленный репозиторий ? Неужели нужно каждый раз вводить команды `git push origin master` и `git push origin develop` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужно. Нужно просто

```
git push --all origin
```